# Hover Title Text in <lightning-datatable> for Data Type "text"

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

Is there any way to get hover text in a `<lightning-datatable>` for a column of type "text"? Surprisingly, it doesn't appear to be supported, even though in HTML, the `title` attribute is accepted on pretty much any element type.

I tried using a button (since that supports a title attribute) with variant "base" so it looks a link, but 1st, I don't want it to be a link, and 2nd, if the text gets too long, it doesn't overflow nicely with the ellipses, instead it goes to 2 lines, making the entire row taller, and it looks awkward.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround: Use type `button` and style it like text.**

[Here's a working example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/XdIzsE4jZDfxg4mcOFLn).

Basically, when setting your data, you'll set the column `type` as 'button', and add a class - in this example, I'm calling the class 'text-button', and this is for an Address field:

```
{
    label: 'Address',
    fieldName: 'address',
    type: 'button',
    typeAttributes: {
        label: { fieldName: 'address' },
        title: { fieldName: 'address' },
        variant: 'base',
        class: 'text-button'
    }
}
```

The corresponding CSS would then need to be:

```
.text-button > button {
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #080707;
}

.text-button > button:hover {
    color: #080707;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got this to work with a little bit of JQuery:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDEHO.png

Steps to take:

1. Load JQuery in parent lightning web component
2. Reference JQuery (ex. $) in your child component
3. Style as necessary with your .css file(s)

See details on steps 1. and 2. code below:

1a.Import the following at your parent LWC level:

```
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import jQuery from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/ent_JQuery';
```

1b. In connectedCallback at your parent LWC level, load JQuery:

```
connectedCallback() {

    loadScript(this, jQuery)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('JQuery loaded.');
    })
    .catch(error=>{
        console.log('Failed to load the JQuery : ' +error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        
    });
    
}
```

2a. Call the JQuery method in your constructor at your child LWC level (where the table headers are!):

```
constructor() {
    super();
    Promise.all([
        loadStyle(this, CustomDataTableResource),
    ]).then(() => {
        this.usejQuery();
    })
}
```

2. Add the tooltip on hover based on the aria-label of the header!

   ```
    usejQuery() {
    var header=$(this.template.querySelector('[aria-label="Days Since Last Activity"]'));
    $(header).hover(function(){
        $(header).append('<div class="slds-popover slds-popover_tooltip slds-nubbin_top-left toolTipDisplay" role="tooltip" id="help"><div class="slds-popover__body popoverText">Days since last activity with a Prospect."</div></div>');
    },function () {
        $(header).children('.toolTipDisplay').remove();
    });}
   ```